# sentiment analysis using python and php -python nltk

Tags: php, python, nltk

I am new to python script i want to create sentiment analysis for the word or phrase whether the text or phrase is positive or negative.by using php post the phrase or text through $_POST['textarea'] and get in python script and check whether the phrase or text is positive or negative i want to use python nltk for example like this(pls see the link)

http://text-processing.com/demo/sentiment/

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'Analyze') {

$data = $_POST['text'];
$tmp = exec("/home/Ismath/Desktop/check.py $data");
echo $tmp;
```

}

//in check.py i want the word or phrase is positive and negative and neutral and how i can get the post value from textarea box in check.py if i use

```
  import sys
  print sys.argv[1]
```

//if i use above code suppose i enter "this is good thing" in php textarea box i got only the first text "this" only in my check.py file i want to print the whole words available in textarea box and through this word i want to check the sentence("this is good thing") is positive or negative by sentimental analysis how

?>

```
<body >
    <div id="main">
        <form action="sentiment.php" method="post" >
            <div id="text-div">Enter Text:</div>
            <textarea rows="12" cols="38" name="text"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Analyze">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

so please anyone can help me how can i proceed with this with php and python 
dont use the api.i wnat to create new corpus ,text in my own pls tell how can i proceed with the steps for exp my php page like this

thanks in advance

Comment: why not use the api? http://text-processing.com/docs/sentiment.html

Comment: Yeah, if you're happy with what the demo does, then use the API. If not, the source code for the classifier is [here](https://github.com/japerk/nltk-trainer), and you can change how it works and the corpus you're using yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an idea.

You can use File Handling in your Php code and write the content of `$data` to a file.
Then instead of passing `$data` as argument, read the file contents from your python code, perform whatever algorithm you want to and print the result so that it gets stored in `$tmp`.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap $data by single quotes

```
$data = htmlentities($data, ENT_QUOTES);
$tmp = exec("/home/Ismath/Desktop/check.py '$data'");
```

python:

```
import sys
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
print HTMLParser().unescape(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: and also i want to check my text is POSITIVE OR NEGATIVE LIKE this link http://text-processing.com/demo/sentiment/ how can i proceed this

Comment: thanks but i type "NLTK is my first work in python" in textarea box iget only the first text NLTK not the full sentence because i use sys.argv[1]-tat mean print only the first how can i print with the "NLTK is my first work in python"